# chain.com Bitcoin API: Does not provide “making wallet” feature?

Tags: wallet, api

chain.com's Bitcoin API is super easy to implement Bitcoin function into my iOS App. Checking the balance of a specific bitcoin address and retrieving transactions are very convenient. However, unlike luxstack.com, chain.com seems not to have "Creating Bitcoin Address" feature. Is it right?

Thanks.

FYI https://chain.com/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they don't support wallet features, only querying the blockchain for addresses, balances and transactions.  From the docs:

```
Get Bitcoin Address
GET /addresses/{address}
Returns basic balance details for one or more Bitcoin addresses.
```